# Python name shadowing confusion

Tags: python, scope

So I've got some code similar to this (this code reproduces my question, even if it doesn't do anything useful):

```
def fn():
    l = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    print map( lambda f : len(f), l )
    for i, f in enumerate(l):
        print i, f
```

And PyCharm is reporting that my declaration of `lambda f` "Shadows name f from outer scope". This appears to be because of the variable being reused in the call to `enumerate()` in the following line.

The code works as expected, but what's happening here? Am I correct in thinking that Python is deciding that `f` is a local variable in `fn` and warning me that the use of `f` inside the lambda isn't going to be the same `f` defined locally - even though the lambda makes use of the variable name `f` first?

Other than renaming variables, is there a best practice for avoiding this - or should I just use my judgement and ignore the warning in this instance?

Comment: If it makes any difference, this is in Python 2.7.

Comment: Just use `print map(len, l)`.

Comment: This is a toy example to illustrate a language feature, not production code.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to a variable anywhere in the definition of a function makes it local to the function. A more typical example is

```
x = 3
def foo():
    print x
    x = 2
foo()
```

When `foo` is defined, the presence of `x = 2` without a previous `global x` statement makes `x` a local variable. When `foo` is called, the local variable `x` is not yet defined when `print x` is called, resulting in an `UnboundLocalError`. It doesn't matter that there is a global variable by the same name.

In your example, the `for` loop is a kind of implicit assignment to the variable `f`, so `f` is local to `fn`. The warning is to let you know that the `lambda` argument `f` takes precedence over the value of `f` in `fn` when it comes time to evaluate `len(f)`.

Comment: sorta-kinda like [javascript hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) except Python doesn't have declarations, except this means it kinda does...